# How to use a sub folder in default controller route in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

While setting `$route['default_controller']` with out sub directory it is working but I wanted to change it inside sub directory and its not working.

Comment: How did you go did you try my answer

Answer (score 13):

By default codeigniter 3 you will not be able to have sub folder in your default_route

You need to use a MY_Router.php

Located in application > core > MY_Router.php

This will enable you to use sub folder in default_controller in CI3

```
<?php

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
    protected function _set_default_controller() {

        if (empty($this->default_controller)) {

            show_error('Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.');
        }
        // Is the method being specified?
        if (sscanf($this->default_controller, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
            $method = 'index';
        }

        // This is what I added, checks if the class is a directory
        if( is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class) ) {

            // Set the class as the directory

            $this->set_directory($class);

            // $method is the class

            $class = $method;

            // Re check for slash if method has been set

            if (sscanf($method, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
                $method = 'index';
            }
        }

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php')) {

            // This will trigger 404 later

            return;
        }
        $this->set_class($class);
        $this->set_method($method);
        // Assign routed segments, index starting from 1
        $this->uri->rsegments = array(
            1 => $class,
            2 => $method
        );
        log_message('debug', 'No URI present. Default controller set.');
    }
}
```

Then this should let you be able to do

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'subfolder/controller/function';
```

Comment: Nice explanation with an example.

Comment: thanks Sir, answer really helps me to understand the route flow, but does not work in `CodeIgniter Version 3.1.0` for me, have you tried it in `3.1.0 version`

Comment: actually it works... sorry for the previous comment...my problem was the wrong file name of `.htaccess` and its work like charm in `CI 3.+`.

Comment: Nice job it works well :)

Comment: Thanks alot :) and yes it's perfectly working with 3.x version