# Codeigniter 3.1.0 routing issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, controllers, custom-routes

I managed to run default controller from sub directory by adding a MY_Router file in application/core, everything works fine but this is what I am facing now.I am unable to route it if url hits /admin or /student or /teacher which is eventually a sub directory in controllers.

```
https://s14.postimg.org/pr3ta38f5/controller_structure.png
  https://s14.postimg.org/z05zk7hb5/error_1.png
  https://s14.postimg.org/mmt5darmp/issue_2.png
  https://s14.postimg.org/kwa4bta3l/page_controller.png
  https://s14.postimg.org/j5voo2hy9/routes.png
```

Comment: what does your MY_Router look like? also couldn't you just put your controller in a sub-directory and point do it from your router default?
$route['default_controller'] = 'directory/controller/method';

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808054/how-to-use-a-sub-folder-in-default-controller-route-in-codeigniter-3

Here is the MY_Router.php code

Answer (score 0):

If you folder structure is thus:

```
- controllers
  - teachers
     - Teacher_home.php

  - students
     - Student_home.php

  - admin
     - Admin_home.php
```

Then normal CI routing would be with URLs to the default index method would be like:

```
mysite/teachers/teacher_home
mysite/students/student_home
mysite/admin/admin_home
```

Your routes could then point mysite/teacher_home to the relevant controller above like this:

```
$route['teacher_home'] = 'teachers/teacher_home';
```

In the CI docs they describe the wild cards you can use: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

But any route must point to a valid controller/method url. Get your site/app working under normal default routing, then add the alternate routing in afterwards.

So remove your current routes. If you have a default route in it will probably be messing up your other routes if you have not written it properly, or in the right order.

Hope that helps,