# How to set default controller with sub folder in codeigntier

Tags: php, codeigniter

My `default_controller` in the routes configuration is set as "`dashboard.php`".

I have a sub directory for my controllers, lets call it "admin" and inside that folder i have controller namely "dashboard.php".

When i set in my route.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'admin/dashboard';
```

throws an Internal Server Error.

Is it possible to  set controller in subfolder as default controller in Codeigniter ?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529026/codeigniter-default-controller-in-a-sub-directory-not-working

Comment: access http://localhost/app_folder/admin will be your default home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter default controller in a sub directory not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529026/codeigniter-default-controller-in-a-sub-directory-not-working)

Comment: please refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808054/how-to-use-a-sub-folder-in-default-controller-route-in-codeigniter-3/34808170

Comment: Thanks for the post !  Its working

Comment: Thanks for the post . Its working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808054/how-to-use-a-sub-folder-in-default-controller-route-in-codeigniter-3/34808170