# PHP CodeIgniter - How to set default page for website root

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter, building website with 2 nested controller directories `backend` and `frontend`. All my pages are working fine except root. I am facing difficulty to set a default page when there is not path specified in url (only the website root).

I want to render home page if there is no path after website root. I put `$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/pages'`, but its not working.

My `config/routes.php` is as follows:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/pages';

$route['user'] = 'user/index';
$route['user/register']['GET'] = 'frontend/user/index';

$route['user/register']['POST'] = 'frontend/user/register_user';
$route['user'] = 'frontend/user/login_view';
$route['user/login'] = 'frontend/user/login_view';
$route['user/login_user'] = 'frontend/user/login_user';
$route['user/user_profile'] = 'frontend/user/user_profile';
$route['user/user_logout'] = 'frontend/user/user_logout';

$route['admin'] = 'backend/Admin_area/dashboard';
$route['admin/(index|dashboard)'] = 'backend/Admin_area/dashboard';
$route['admin/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'backend/$1/$2/$3';
$route['admin/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'backend/$1/$2';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'backend/$1';

$route['/^$'] = 'frontend/pages/view/home';
$route['(:any)'] = 'frontend/pages/view/$1';
```

When I visit `root/` is show me `404 error page`.

`Pages` Controller code:

```
<?php
class Pages extends Frontend_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $page = 'home';
            $this->data['pagetitle'] = ucfirst($page); 

            $this->render('pages/'. $page);
    }

        public function view($page = 'home')
    {

            $this->data['pagetitle'] = ucfirst($page); 

            $this->render('pages/'. $page);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show pages controller?

Comment: @pradeep Pages controller code added in question.

Comment: Frontend_Controller  should be CI_Controller

Comment: Yes that inherit from CI_Controller. also home,about,contact pages using Page Controller, and working fine.

Comment: are you set any .htaccess  rules for routing ?

Comment: I have this file in root directory, but I did not make any changes there.

Comment: can you share other working page url ?

Comment: These are working:
http://localhost:8080/ci2/home
http://localhost:8080/ci2/about
http://localhost:8080/ci2/contact

But this is not working:
http://localhost:8080/ci2/

Comment: why are you used port 8080? i think it`s working well with : http://localhost/ci2/home

Comment: I am using XAMPP with localhost, I think in default settings it is using this port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171381/discussion-between-reena-mori-and-m-idrees).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in codeigniter the default controller route can only be on the first level of controllers.

All other controller can in a sub folder but just not the default controller you want to have.

Correct

```
application
application > controllers
application > controllers > Pages.php // Your Default Controller
```

Not

```
application
application > controllers
application > controllers > frontend > Pages.php
```

---

> **To be able to have sub folders for default_controller route**

Like

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'subfolder/controller/function';
```

[How to use a sub folder in default controller route in CodeIgniter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808054/how-to-use-a-sub-folder-in-default-controller-route-in-codeigniter-3?lq=1)

You will need to  create a application/core/MY_Router.php file

```
<?php

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    protected function _set_default_controller() {

        if (empty($this->default_controller)) {

            show_error('Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.');
        }
        // Is the method being specified?
        if (sscanf($this->default_controller, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
            $method = 'index';
        }

        // This is what I added, checks if the class is a directory
        if( is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class) ) {

            // Set the class as the directory

            $this->set_directory($class);

            // $method is the class

            $class = $method;

            // Re check for slash if method has been set

            if (sscanf($method, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
                $method = 'index';
            }
        }

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php')) {

            // This will trigger 404 later

            return;
        }
        $this->set_class($class);
        $this->set_method($method);
        // Assign routed segments, index starting from 1
        $this->uri->rsegments = array(
            1 => $class,
            2 => $method
        );
        log_message('debug', 'No URI present. Default controller set.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to make it bit more clear pretty easy for to understand.

Comment: Thanks for adding explanation. So for controllers in subfolders, it needs to create custom router inheriting default one and then set variables like $directory, $class, $method manually to that it can load these things from subfolder.

Comment: @M_Idrees All other controllers are fine in sub folders but just the one that you want to have as a default controller can not be. Unless you create that MY_Router.php file example I have.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks @Mr. ED, it helps to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

*On CodeIgniter 3 It does not allow you to have a sub folder on `$route['default_controller']` you will instead need to create a `MY_Router`.php file like below.*

You will need to create a MY_Router.php in

```
application > core > MY_Router.php
```

```
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
protected function _set_default_controller() {

    if (empty($this->default_controller)) {

        show_error('Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.');
    }
    // Is the method being specified?
    if (sscanf($this->default_controller, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
        $method = 'index';
    }

    // This is what I added, checks if the class is a directory
    if( is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class) ) {

        // Set the class as the directory

        $this->set_directory($class);

        // $method is the class

        $class = $method;

        // Re check for slash if method has been set

        if (sscanf($method, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
            $method = 'index';
        }
    }

    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php')) {

        // This will trigger 404 later

        return;
    }
    $this->set_class($class);
    $this->set_method($method);
    // Assign routed segments, index starting from 1
    $this->uri->rsegments = array(
        1 => $class,
        2 => $method
    );
    log_message('debug', 'No URI present. Default controller set.');
}
}
```

In route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/pages';
```

Comment: yes changed to this. but still same result. home,about,contact pages working, but default (empty or /) path not working.

Comment: pls try with removing index method from your controller

Comment: Tried. Still no luck.

Comment: @pradeep You need to modify / create a special MY_Router.php to have subfolder for default controller as in my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Change This**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/pages';
```

**Change To**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/pages';
$route['default_controller'] = "pages";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try changing controller with:**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
```

Comment: Getting same result.

Answer (score -1):

You can override 404 default mechanism using:-

```
$route['404_override'] = 'your_custom_or_default_page';
```

And default controller as:-

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'your_custom_or_default_page';
```

Comment: still getting same response.

Comment: I know it's just for 404 error page, but the user has clearly mentioned in the query, that **I want to render home page if there is no path after website root**. 
Therefore, overriding of 404 error page will help to render the default page in case there's no resource available for the given url